# Getting values from inner functions of current webpage in Chrome via (JXA / AppleScript)

Tags: macos, google-chrome, applescript, javascript-automation

I can't get values from inner functions of current webpage in Chrome. Why it's happened?

for examples in JXA:

```js
function getTime() {
    const chrome = Application('Google Chrome')
    const currentTab = chrome.windows[0].activeTab()
    return currentTab.execute({javascript: 'jwplayer().getPosition()'})
}
getTime()
```

Chrome returns reference error:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: jwplayer is not defined
```

in AppleScript the same:

```
tell application "Google Chrome"
    return execute front window's active tab javascript "jwplayer().getPosition()"
end tell
```

Settings in Chrome is checked: "Allow Javascript from Apple Events"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Founded a workaround with AppleScript:

```
tell front window of application "Google Chrome"
    set URL of active tab to "javascript:
    sessionStorage.setItem('scrapy', JSON.stringify({
      currentTime: jwplayer().getPosition()
    }, 2, '  ')
  "
    return {execute active tab javascript "sessionStorage.getItem('scrapy')"}
end tell
```

Comment: any idea how this can be written in javascript?